# Georeferencing image from Google Earth?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, image

What I want to do appears simple. However, there seems to be a bug.

I have an image from GE which I want to georeference and set as a background layer. I thus set some placemarks on GE, wrote down the coordinates, created a picture and uploaded it to the georeferencer. I then wanted to put in the coordinates for the placemarks manually, however, they do not fit. In order to see which would be kinf of fitting coordinates, I chose the "from map canvas option" and got totally different coordinates for which I can't make out the unit at all. I have specified WGS 84 everywhere as coordinate system and I also have some other layers on QGIS, which display the correct lat/ long values when asked by the information function.

Do you know what mistake I could have made?

Comment: In addition to Andre's answer, make sure that Google Earth is set to Decimal Degrees, and not DMS, or other systems like UTM, when you copy the coordinates.

Comment: Please note that if you are saving Images from Google Earth and georeferencing them, you are breaking Google's T&C.

Answer (score 1):

If you grab lat/lon coordinates from GE, you have to set the target CRS in the Georeferencer settings to `EPSG:4326`.

If you take coordinates from the QGIS map canvas using the Openlayers plugin, the units are (Google) meters, and the target has to be `EPSG:3857`.

You can not mix both methods.