# Problem aligning historic map of Poland

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, georeferencing

I have downloaded a historic map of [Poland](http://www.davidrumsey.com/luna/servlet/detail/RUMSEY~8~1~24837~960045:Poland,-Prussia-?&qvq=mgid:47942&mi=1&trs=2).
I am having a problem aligning it to a modern map. I have tried various methods and coordinate system using over 50 points, but nothing works. It gets close, but never close enough. The best is when projected by Georeferencer from that site, but I cannot save it as GeoTIFF.

Comment: You'll want to research and possibly ask about extracting vector data from a raster separately from this question. This site works best with single focused questions.

Comment: It sounds like the problem exporting to GeoTIFF is one that could be made the focus of this question using the [edit] button beneath it to remove the other.

Comment: I narrowed it down. Just need to properly export it to GeoTiff

Comment: What software version are you using since you didn't mention it...

Comment: Blue Marble has a tool that might help. http://www.bluemarblegeo.com/about-us/press.php?id=179

Comment: I am using 2.14.2 Essen. Do I need Blue Marble Desktop 2.0, or Global Mapper? which tool you are referring to?

Comment: QGIS is good enough for georeferencing. You just need to [edit] your question, insert a screenshot of the georeferencing settings form. We need to know which transformation, resampling and SRS you have chosen, and how you grab the coordinates.

Comment: I tried all settings and re-sampling, and save all of them, some too much to the left, some the other way, Polynomial and thin plate seems to be the best. Thin plate with nearest neighbor in the center of the map looks disent, but on the bottom is not.

Comment: <img src="http://file:///C:/Users/pilip/Desktop/linear%202.jpg" >

Comment: It probably has to do with Geo coordinate system. I project it in WGS 84 (4326), When loaded I cannot see it unless change settings to WGS 84 (3857). For some reason I cannot upload pictures.

Comment: !file:///C:/Users/pilip/Desktop/linear%202.jpg

Comment: Can you suggest proper setting?

Comment: A link to your local disk will not work over the internet. My answers to these questions might solve your problem: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98141/georeferencing-an-image-from-googleearth and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165876/using-openlayers-and-georeferencer-plugin-with-solution-in-qgis. Thin pate spline and nearest neighbour should be ok.

Comment: Have you tried using Map Tiler ? http://www.maptiler.com/features/   I will be doing the same thing with one of the maps I have in Russia. I still have not have the time to do...

Comment: ROBERT, I have tried using Map Tiler. It exports KMZ, and also does not have full accuracy.  Thank you AndreJ for help, I had figured that trick with Open Layer in the past< so it is not a problem. Map is getting closer, but still not quite there. Different settings shift cities, and roads, but non evenly .

Comment: You can still edit your question to insert images. Otherwise it is hard to tell what goes wrong. Keep in mind that the map is very old, and surveying was not very accurate at the time.

Comment: The best settings for this map is Thin plate pline with either cubic spline, or Lanczo resampling. Geoprogections are withing 4 -6 km. The only draw back, map looks very distorted at the left lower corner. That is where labels and mountains are. I am not interested in this area. Would be still nice to find the way to do it better.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40337/discussion-on-question-by-roman-pilip-problem-aligning-historic-map-of-poland).